# How to run Socket.io on top of Nodejs express endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, routes

I would like to keep everything within one server which is why I'd like to implement a socket.io server that handles connections from my products on top of my authentication web server.

At the moment, I have a middleware function that verifies if the given auth-token is valid:

verifyToken.js:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(req, res, next){

// Check if auth-token is avaliable
const token = req.header('auth-token');
if(!token) return res.status(401).send('Access denied');

try{
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, "secret");
    req.user = verified;
    next()
}catch (err){
    // Invalid token - not logged in 
    res.status(201).send('Access denied');
    }
}
```

I can use this middle-ware on any endpoint that should be only accessed by a logged in, valid user:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const verify = require('../authentication_routes/verifyToken');

router.get('/', verify, (req,res) => {
    res.send('logged in');
});

module.exports = router;
```

How would I implement a socket.io server in this router, the NodeJS app itself runs from port 3000 and id like anyone that hits the endpoint that goes to this router get connected to a socket.io server.
I've tried this:

```
    const router = require('express').Router();
    const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
    const verify = require('../authentication_routes/verifyToken');

router.get('/', verify, (req,res) => {
    io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.emit('connection-established', 'Connected');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But it obviously doesn't work as port 3000 is already in use by the NodeJS server.

How would I go about this, I know there are questions out there that (somewhat) answer this, but it does not include the fact that I'm using a middle-ware function on a protected endpoint?

Comment: Are you passing your express ``app`` to ``http.createServer()``? If so, you could put the socket.io server at your main file, pass the node.js http server to the socket.io server constructor, and use [socket.io middleware](https://socket.io/docs/namespaces/#Namespace-middleware) to authenticate the request.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes I have not, could you provide some code or links that could help me, I’ve only ever used one way and that way is in the question. What’s the difference in the method you’ve just said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get `/` endpoint if user is authenticated it should render HTML page to user (The chat interface) Your code should be like this

```
  const router = require('express').Router();
  const server = require("http").Server(router)
  const io = require("socket.io")(server)
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000
  server.listen(port)
  const verify = require('../authentication_routes/verifyToken');

  router.get('/', verify, (req,res) => {
      io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.emit('connection-established', 'Connected');
    });
  });


  

  module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The problem is, I can't run a nodejs server on port 3000 with a socket.io server also on port 3000, I'm not sure how that fixes my problem?

Comment: I have edited the answer, have a look. See if that works or not.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look, however this is a backend API, I want the user to have a connection to my server via socket when and only when they are authenticated, hence the middleware. So I am not displaying any HTML, just want to grant access to the socket connection when the middleware has been confirmed, can you update your answer to show that?

Comment: The above answer still doesn't work, the port is still being used by express so it throws an error

Comment: Ok. Somewhere in your code did you connect to that port, if so then try after removing that code. You only require one connection to the port in the entire application.

Comment: Same thing, the error 'ADDRESS IN USE' for port 3000, my express is running off 3000 too.

Comment: If possible can you show me your full code? Like GitHub link

Comment: I got it, I just had some errors in my other code and your code worked, cheers!